# Android Studio lost the References

Tags: android, android-studio

Today when I open my project the android studio doesn't find the references of things, yesterday the app was running correcly when turn off the Windows had updated and when started Android Studio update too, I saw something about gradle but put it in local/offline doesn't works

[Printscreen with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcB4i.png)

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the problem is with Android Studio caches. Try "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart...", and select "Invalidate and Restart".

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the project: Build -> Clean Project

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove or rename the Android SDK folder and restart the Android Studio. It will be recreated SDK folder. And you can use it normally.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my RecyclerViewAdapter and it resolved the problem by deleting "R.android.r". I am not sure if this is a specific situation for me but see if you can find it within your import section.

Comment: please put more description

Comment: Check the file that has the "Missing Reference" header and see if there are any imports that might be causing it. If there's "R.android.r" then try deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading the grade plugin, then increase your compileSDKtarget version, then apply the Kotlin migration.

Lastly, Build your app
These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If suggested answers did not solve the problem then try this.

`File > Repair IDE > Rescan Project`

It will show action to perform which includes Rescan, Reopen, re-indexing project and invalidate cache & restart